# mySQL: IF и REGEXP, вытащить подстроку

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Если запрос отработал и имеются результаты, то как добавить условие в запрос, которое бы с помощью REGEXP вытаскивало из полученной строки после /command (поля subject) подстроку, при условии, что она содержит текст, а не только пробелы.

Получаю последнюю строку:

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE subject LIKE '/command %' ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Например, по результату получаем:

```
/command просто текст
```

С помощью конструкции IF и REGEXP в запросе нужно вытащить:

```
просто текст
```

Если после /command нет символов или идут пробельные символы, то присвоить NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

`REGEXP` в `MySQL` возвращает либо 0, либо 1. Т.е. `match | not match` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Пролистайте все примеры, вы увидите, лишь 0 или 1 в ответах.

---

Вам лучше воспользоваться другими `STRING FUNCTIONS` `MySQL` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Например: `SUBSTRING()`.
Вот такой вариант выведет Вам все, что находится после '/command ' в колонке 'subject'

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`subject`, LENGTH('/command ')) 
FROM entries
WHERE subject LIKE '/command %' 
ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1
```